# format number with insert space by regex

Tags: regex

I have a number like this: `09123456789`. I want to format this like: `0912 345 6789`. How can I do by regex?

Comment: Surely you don't need a regex for that. But still, in case no other option is there, check [this](https://regex101.com/r/0sccSr/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better approaches than regex in most languages. However, if you must do it with regex, you should be able to find a facility that inserts a matched group into the output, and use it to format the result.

For example, in Java you use `$N` to reference a capturing group number `N`, i.e. `$1` for the first group, `$2` for the second one, and so on. Hence, re-formatting of 11-digit string with two spaces would look like this:

```
String s = "09123456789";
String r = s.replaceAll("(\\d{4})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})", "$1 $2 $3");
```

Regex captures groups of 4-3-4 digits, then `$1 $2 $3` inserts the spaces in between the groups.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/SLgOur)